# Ordering an array based on 2D array of relations (higher, lower, doesn't matter)

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have been stuck with this problem for two days and I still can't get it right.

Basically, I have a 2D array with relations between certain numbers (in given range):

- 0 = the order doesn't matter
- 1 = the first number (number in left column) should be first
- 2 = the second number (number in upper row) should be first

So, I have some 2D array, for example this:

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 2
1 0 0 2 0 0 0 0
2 2 1 0 0 1 0 0
3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 2 0 0 0 0
5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
6 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

And my goal is to create a new array of given numbers (0 - 6) in such a way that it is following the rules from the 2D array (e.g. 0 is before 2 but it is after 6). I probably also have to check if such array exists and then create the array. And get something like this:

```
6 0 2 1 4 5
```

### My Code

(It doesn't really matter, but I prefer c++)

So far I tried to start with ordered array `0123456` and then swap elements according to the table (but that obviously can't work). I also tried inserting the number in front of the other number according to the table, but it doesn't seem to work either.

```cpp
// My code example
// I have:
//    relArr[n][n]             - array of relations
//    resArr = {1, 2, ... , n} - result array

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
        if (relArr[i][x] == 1) {
          // Finding indexes of first (i) and second (x) number
            int iI = 0;
            int iX = 0;
            while (resArr[iX] != x)
                iX++;
            while (resArr[iI] != i)
                iI++;

          // Placing the (i) before (x) and shifting array
            int tmp, insert = iX+1;
            if (iX < iI) {
                tmp = resArr[iX];
                resArr[iX] = resArr[iI];

                while (insert < iI+1) {
                    int tt = resArr[insert];
                    resArr[insert] = tmp;
                    tmp = tt;
                    insert++;
                }
            }
        } else if (relArr[i][x] == 2) {
            int iI = 0;
            int iX = 0;
            while (resArr[iX] != x)
                iX++;
            while (resArr[iI] != i)
                iI++;

            int tmp, insert = iX-1;
          if (iX > iI) {
                tmp = resArr[iX];
                resArr[iX] = resArr[iI];

                while (insert > iI-1) {
                    int tt = resArr[insert];
                    resArr[insert] = tmp;
                    tmp = tt;
                    insert--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I probably miss correct way how to check whether or not it is possible to create the array. Feel free to use vectors if you prefer them.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: As described, there's no way to prevent conflicting input, or incomplete input. In the example you've given there's no information for `3` or `5` so where should they go in the output?

Comment: I didn't understand your questions well, can you clarify it more. "And my goal is to create a new array of given numbers (0 - 6)" do you mean you want a 1D array or a 2D array?

Comment: Look at [Topological_sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).

Comment: @JackDeeth If there's no information for certain numbers, they can go anywhere. I just need at least one output, which satisfy the conditions.

Comment: A quick check if the matrix is not self-contradictory at first (a(i,j)==a(j,i) and both > 0 or a(i,i)>0 will immediately signal a cycle) and consistent (if a(i,j)>0 then a(j,i)>0) and then you can rely only on the upper right triangle. After that, it's a topological sorting problem indeed - in which you need to keep track of the relation that you already visited to detect of a longer cycle exists: if so, there's no solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion.

As suggested, only ones `1` are important in 2D array. I used them to create vector of directed edges and then I implemented Topological Sort. I decide to use this [Topological Sorting Algorithm](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/topological-sorting-indegree-based-solution/). It is basically Topological Sort, but it also checks for the cycle.

This successfully solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be re-ordering the output at the same time as you're reading the input. I think you should parse the input into a set of rules, process the rules a bit, then re-order the output at the end.

---

What are the constraints of the problem? If the input says that `0` goes before `1`:

```
  | 0 1
--+----
0 |   1
1 |
```

does it also guarantee that it will say that `1` comes after `0`?

```
  | 0 1
--+----
0 |   
1 | 2
```

If so you can forget about the `2`s and look only at the `1`s:

```
  | 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
--+--------------
0 |     1
1 |
2 |   1     1
3 |
4 |
5 |
6 | 1
```

---

From reading the input I would store a list of rules. I'd use `std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>` for this. It has the nice feature that `yourPair.first` comes before `yourPair.second` :)

```
0 before 2
2 before 1
2 before 4
6 before 0
```

You can discard any rules where the second value is never the first value of a different rule.

```
0 before 2
6 before 0
```

This list would then need to be sorted so that "... before **x**" and "**x** before ..." are guaranteed to be in that order.

```
6 before 0
0 before 2
```

Then move `6`, `0`, and `2` to the front of the list `0123456`, giving you `6021345`.

Does that help?